# Repeat a record for every day between two dates BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am attempting to produce a table of historical unfulfilled units. Currently, the database captures fulfillment date and order date for a record.

```
CREATE TABLE `input_table`
(order_name STRING,
line_item_id STRING, 
order_date DATE, 
fulfillment_date DATE)
```

Sample Record:
order_name: ABC
line_item_id: 123456
order_date: 2017-04-19
fulfillment_date: 2017-04-25

I want to produce a table that shows the fulfillment status by day, starting with the order date and ending with the date prior to the fulfillment date of each line item, e.g. in the above sample record the `output_table` would be:

[image]

Ultimately, this would allow me to query the count of unfulfilled line items each day:

```
SELECT 
date,
count(line_item_id) AS unfulfilled_line_items 
FROM 
`output_table`
GROUP BY 1
```

Indicating the fulfillment status is not strictly necessary, considering it would only include dates in which the status was unfulfilled.

While I could do something like this:

```
with days as (SELECT
*
FROM 
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2017-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)) AS day)

SELECT 
* 
FROM 
`input_table` 
JOIN days 
ON 1=1 
AND order_date <= day
AND fulfillment_date > day
```

..the operation is fairly expensive.

Is there a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to produce a table that shows the fulfillment status by day, starting with the order date and ending with the date prior to the fulfillment date of each line item

Consider below

```
select date, order_name, line_item_id, 'unfulfilled' fulfillment_status
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(generate_date_array(order_date, fulfillment_date - 1)) date
```

if applied to sample entry in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works well. For my own education, could you explain why this is faster for processing time?

Comment: Instead of producing one big array of dates, you create small array of dates specific for each given row so join is much cheaper